# How to use VarD to vary $\partial T$

Tags: xact, variational-calculus

I know that how the VarD works which is $ VarD[T, covd][expr] $. What about when I want to vary to a partial of a tensor ($\partial T)$? Let me say a simple question I wanted to test:
$ L = \partial_{a}h_{\mu \nu}\partial^{a}h^{\mu\nu}$.To use VarD I write: $VarD[\partial_{a}h_{\mu \nu},PD][L]$ but it gives zero to me. Could anybody tell me how I can vary this simple L which its variation is clear?